# how to make the for loop not skip the last two elements in the list?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to subtract every element in the list from the first lower value after it even if the lower value of the element is not in the next index
for example, I have the list [ 7,18,5,5,20,9,14,21,19]
it should produce [ 2,13,5,5,11,9,14,2,19]

```
   for i in range(len(numeric_list)-2):  
     if numeric_list[i] >numeric_list[i+1]:
         msg[i] = numeric_list[i] - numeric_list[i+1]  
     elif numeric_list [i]<numeric_list[i+1] and numeric_list[i]>numeric_list[i+2]   :
         msg[i]= numeric_list[i]-numeric_list[i+2]
     else :
         msg[i]=numeric_list[i]
```

I have used this code but the for loop skips the last two elements of the list, I tried to change the range of the loop but it gives me ' list out of range' because of the elif statement

Comment: it skips because You are not going over every list item, try adding a try except and catch the list out of index error and assign the next item in the list since it will be the next lowest value and for the last value it will always be 0 because you can't go any further

Comment: It'll be wrong anyway, since you're only checking the next two values. Do it right, and likely the problem you ask about will vanish automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified the code and inserted few comments. Hope, it helps -

```
list1 =  [ 7,18,5,5,20,9,14,21,19]
result= []
for index,i in enumerate(list1): # enumerate will provide index value which can be used for list slicing later
    k=0 # flag this will check if the smaller number is available or not
    for j in list1[index+1:]: # we need to take only those list items which comes after the element
        if j < i :
            result.append(i-j) # if number is found change the value of k and break the loop
            k=1
            break
    if k ==0: # if the smaller number is not found don't change the value and insert the same number. 
        result.append(i)
print(result)
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a shorter solution (linewise) for Your issue:

```py
list1 = [7, 18, 5, 5, 20, 9, 14, 21, 19]

result = [number - [value if value < number else 0 for value in list1[index + 1 if index + 1 < len(list1) else index:]][0] for index, number in enumerate(list1)]
print(result)
```

basically it is a complex list comprehension (never made anything this complex) but it works

Comment: no what i meant is subtracting every element from the first lower value after it for example the first lower value after 7 is 5 so 7-5 , first lower value after 20 is 9 so 20 -9 and so on

Comment: @om1999 yes that is what it does takes the next lowest value and subtracts it from the current one

Comment: @Manuel yes they do, he wanted to subtract from each value in the list the next lowest one, which I will show in the edit

Comment: @Manuel ok so first it actually says: "subtract every element in the list from the first lower value" which would mean for example 5 - 7 is the first value, second I noticed my mistake at not properly interpreting "lower" which I assumed meant lowest (don't know why) but apparently meant the first value after the current that is lower than the current

Comment: @om1999 I updated my solution to hopefully this time match Your needs

Comment: @Manuel I made changes and agree that I made a mistake at some point while interpreting what was meant but now I solved the issue and the solution should work as intended